# Problemas com Json Encode do PHP?

Tags: php, json

algo estranho esta ocorrendo na saída de minha função. Quando utilizado o var_dump apenas na variável ele retorna chave e valor normalmente. Pedaço do código:

```
public function buildGender()
{
    $unknow_name = array();

    foreach ( $this->author_comment as $key => $value) 
    {
        $first_name = split(' ',$value);

        if  ( isset( $this->genders[ trim( $first_name[ 0 ] ) ] ) )
        {                
            $this->gender_comment[$key] = $this->genders[$first_name[0]];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->gender_comment[$key] = '0';
            $unknow_name[] = $first_name[0];
        }

    }

    foreach ( $this->author_reply as $key => $value) 
    {
        $first_name = split( ' ',$value );

        if  ( isset( $this->genders[ trim( $first_name[0] ) ] ) ) 
        {                
            $this->gender_reply[$key] = $this->genders[$first_name[0]];
        }
        else
        {
            $this->gender_reply[$key] = '0';
            $unknow_name[] = $first_name[0];
        }
    }

    foreach ( $unknow_name as $key ) 
    {
        $PDO = Database::connect();
        $SQL = "INSERT INTO sys_name_gender ( name,classification ) VALUES (?,?) on conflict(name) do nothing";
        $DATA = array($key,'0'); 
        $SQL  = $PDO->prepare($SQL);
        $SQL->execute($DATA);
        $PDO = Database::disconnect();
    }

    //var_dump(array_count_values($this->gender_comment)  );
    echo json_encode( array( 'gender_reply' => array_count_values( $this->gender_reply ), 'gender_comment' => array_count_values( $this->gender_comment ) ) );

}
```

Essa função pega o primeiro nome, compara com minha base de nomes classificados e caso tenha retorna uma string *`0 | 1 | 2`*. Caso seja **0** ele insere o nome para futuramente ser classificado.

**A saída fica assim:**

```
{"gender_reply":{"1":3,"0":24,"2":4},"gender_comment":[5341,358,3478]}
```

**teria que ficar assim:**

```
{"gender_reply":{"1":3,"0":24,"2":4},"gender_comment":{"1":358,"0":5341,"2":3478}}
```

no var_dump ele mostra corretamente as chaves e valores, isso tirando apenas o json_encode

Alguém sabe o motivo dele formatar assim essa JSON?

ficou assim:

```
$_gender_reply   = array_count_values( $this->gender_reply );
        $_gender_comment = array_count_values( $this->gender_comment );

        $_zero = $_gender_comment['0']+$_gender_reply['0'];
        $_one  = $_gender_comment['1']+$_gender_reply['1'];
        $_two  = $_gender_comment['2']+$_gender_reply['2'];
        $total = $_zero+$_one+$_two; 

        echo json_encode( array( 'total' => $total-$_zero, '%homem' => number_format($_one/($total-$_zero)*100,'2'), '%mulher' => number_format($_two/($total-$_zero)*100,'2') ) );
```

Funcionou perfeitamente, mas gostaria de saber o motivo dele não montar o JSON da forma correta.

Comment: Mostre um exemplo de como deveria retornar. Mostre um exemplo também do que retorna o teste do var_dump()

Comment: Daniel, agradeço o interesse em ajudar. No var_dump eu ele mostra normalmente a saída chave e valor de ambos, eu contornei a situação fazendo mais um filtro e aproveitei pra colocar os campos ja calculados ao invés de tratar no js. Mas é estranho esse tipo de bug, ainda investigo a causa disso. Atualizarei na postagem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quando os índices do array são todos numéricos, o `json_enconde()` não retorna o par `"chave":"valor"` e apresenta apenas os valores, ordenados pelo índice.

Um exemplo mais claro:

```
$array = array(0 => 5341, 1 => 358, 2 => 3478);
echo json_encode($array);
```

retorno:

```
{[5341,358,3478]}
```

Se existir uma chave não numérica:

```
$array = array(0 => 5341, 1 => 358, 2 => 3478, 'foo' => 444);
```

Retorna o par `"chave":"valor"`

```
{"0":5341,"1":358,"2":3478,"string":444}
```

Para exibir as chaves de arrays com índices somente numéricos, pode usar o segundo parâmetro com o valor da constante `JSON_FORCE_OBJECT`.

```
$array = array(0 => 5341, 1 => 358, 2 => 3478);
echo json_encode($array, JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Retorno:

```
{"0":5341,"1":358,"2":3478}
```

Consulte: http://php.net/manual/en/json.constants.php

Para sanar dúvidas, fiz um teste simulando o que supostamente tem no array, conforme descrito na pergunta:

```
//5341,358,3478
//$arr = array('0', '0', '0', '1', '1', '1');
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5341; $i++) {
    $arr[] = 0;
    if ($i <= 358) {
        $arr[] = 1;
    }
    if ($i <= 3478) {
        $arr[] = 2;
    }
}
//var_dump(array_count_values($arr));
//echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.json_encode(array_count_values($arr));
echo PHP_EOL.PHP_EOL.json_encode(array_count_values($arr), JSON_FORCE_OBJECT);
```

Fiz isso porque o array é grande, tem 9 mil valores aproximadamente. Então pensei que poderia ser algo com memória, mas o resultado deu o que era esperado. Como as chaves são numéricas, o `json_encode()` retorna somente os valores.

<sub>obs: As chaves numéricas num array são somente números inteiros. Números fracionários são ignorados.</sub>

Comment: Agradeço a colaboração, mas tem uma questão apenas que não me ficou claro. As variáveis recebem o mesmo tipo de dados, passo as chaves como string (embora com número, não sei se estaria correto). Uma retorna o par, e outra não. Isso que esta me deixando intrigado. Pois o 0 | 1 | 2 são tags internas nossas. Para desconhecido, homem ou mulher, não índice do array. Mas excelente explanação.

Comment: Quando aplica o `array_count_values()`, os índices numéricos tornam-se do tipo numérico, mesmo que no array estejam como strings. Mas não faz muito sentido o outro array retornar as chaves como se fosse um array associativo pois são também numéricos.

Comment: Genial!!! Esqueci desse detalhe do array_count_values(), mas ficamos no caso de um dar certo e outro não. De qualquer forma, estou colocando mais um foreach e filtrando os resultados e incrementando em outro array para não ficar parado nesse estágio.

Comment: A questão da memória o array principal tem aproximadamente essa quantidade de registro, mas tem um outro array que chego em 60k posições, o que faz a quebra do comentário para análise palavra a palavra. Deixei o limite de memória para script com 512mb, meu servidor tem 64gb de RAM e estimativa de 10 ~20 acessos simultâneos.